# Error with Linux Mint 19 and QEMU not booting up

Tags: linux-mint, qemu

I am running qemu on Windows on a 64-bit computer. I am trying to run Linux mint iso with Qemu in powershell. This is my command to run it in powershell.

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -boot d -cdrom E:\linuxmint-19.iso -m 512 -hda LinuxM19.img, -drive format=raw,file=E:\Data.vhd
```

I am booting the iso from a USB and the LinuxM19.img is saved in the folder where all the Qemu stuff is. I made that file using Qemu.

My problem is when i select start Linux it takes a few seconds to load then it shows a black screen with this error message in powershell.

```
WARNING: Image format was not specified for 'LinuxM19.img' and probing guessed raw.
         Automatically detecting the format is dangerous for raw images, write operations on block 0 will be restricted.
         Specify the 'raw' format explicitly to remove the restrictions.
```

Then it goes to the selection menu where i can select to install it or run it i enter the run mode and i get a blank window and in powershell it says:

```
(qemu-system-x86_64.exe:20488): Gtk-WARNING **: Could not load a pixbuf from /org/gtk/libgtk/theme/Adwaita/assets/check-symbolic.svg
This may indicate that pixbuf loaders or the mime database could not be found.
```

I am using `powershell` since `cmd` is blocked on my account.

Comment: how would i manage to make the amount more

Comment: I did this to create the img file .\qemu-img create LinuxM19.img 2G so i dont think that is the problem

Comment: I got linux to boot then it took me to the linux mint loading menu. It took a while to load i got a I/O error then the screen glitched and a grey linux mint logo appeared everywhere then my computer started to automatically resize the window

Comment: @Dextron by changing its `-m` option from 512, eg. `-m 4G`

Comment: How did you install QEMU? From MSYS or sometthing else? If so I have seen that perhaps installing `shared-mime-info` and `gdk-pixbuf2` with *pacman* may help. Try that.

Comment: I downloaded it from the qemu website and then installed it on to the USB and copied it over

Comment: **Please provide all the links to all the files you downloaded.** There are 1000's of files out there matching your description, so making it impossible to help without more details. Also, don't save or run this in the qemu home dir. You should set your path to get this properly found from anywhere.

Comment: @rui-f-ribeiro , @thomas et.al. It's too bad you consider this as OT, since *this* SE is the only one with the most Q/A posts with the `qemu` tag. virtualization would perhaps need it's own SE, but is also considered too niche for getting over the threshold for creating a new SE. Please re-consider. Especially since the qemu CLI options for all systems are the same, even if compiled for windows.

Comment: qemu is the only virtual/emulation tool i can use to run different operating systems as it runs on a heavily restricted school computer and i cannot just ask for them to install virtualBox.

Comment: @Dextron Please re-post this in the `Superuser` or `ServerFault` SE's.